# Problem of using Turtlebot to process image

Tags: ros, opencv, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone ! I'm doing image processing using turtlebot right now, and I have completed programming on VS Windows, it is going perfect, but when I transformed it to ROS, it just went wrong.
I am new in this area so I don't know what to do it right, I followed the tutorials and some simple example, and I successfully generated the exe file, **but when I rosrun my node, the terminal says 'segmentation fault '.**

Here is my program, it's pretty simple even though it looks long:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp> 
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        ros::init(argc, argv, "environment_changes");
        ros::NodeHandle ench;
    //ParametersSetting
    unsigned char t = 50;                                           //difference threashold
    int w = 50;                                             //window for checking
    int output = 0;                                         //output for whether there are changes
    double  threashold = (2 * w - 1)*(2 * w - 1)*0.92;      //threashold for whether there are changes
    double  r = 0.05;                                       //rate of elimated size
    double  X = 0;                                          //x of the centre
    double  Y = 0;                                          //y of the centre
    int p = 0;                                              //number of the changed space
    int i;                                                  //rows
    int j;                                                  //cols

    //LoadImage
    IplImage * image_ref;
    IplImage * image_trans;
    image_ref = cvLoadImage("test1.jpg");
    image_trans = cvLoadImage("test2.jpg");

    //ChangeToGray
    IplImage * image_ref_gray;
    IplImage * image_trans_gray;
    image_ref_gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image_ref), image_ref ->depth ,1);
    image_trans_gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image_trans), image_trans -> depth ,1);
    cvCvtColor(image_ref, image_ref_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    cvCvtColor(image_trans, image_trans_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    //ShowImage
    cvNamedWindow("test1", 1);
    cvNamedWindow("test2", 1);
    cvShowImage("test1", image_ref_gray);
    cvShowImage("test2", image_trans_gray);
    waitKey(0);

    //ComputeTheImage
    IplImage * image_sub;
    image_sub = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image_ref_gray), image_ref_gray->depth, 1);
    Mat ref;
    Mat trans;
    Mat sub;
    ref = Mat(image_ref_gray);
    trans = Mat(image_trans_gray);
    sub = Mat(image_sub);
    absdiff(trans, ref, sub);
        i = sub.rows;
    j = sub.cols;
    int m;
    int n;
    for (m = round(i*r); m <= round(i*(1 - r)); m++){
        for (n = round(j*r); n <= round(j*(1 - r)); n++){
            if (sub.at<uchar>(m, n) >= t){
                sub.at<uchar>(m, n) = 255;
                X = X + m;
                Y = Y + n;
                p = p + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    X = X / p;
    Y = Y / p;
    cout << X << " " << Y << endl;
    * image_sub = IplImage(sub);
    cvNamedWindow("test3", 1);
    cvShowImage("test3", image_sub);
    waitKey(0);

    //ReleaseTheSpace
    cvDestroyWindow("test3");
    cvDestroyWindow("test2");
    cvDestroyWindow("test1");
    cvReleaseImage(&image_sub);
    cvReleaseImage(&image_trans_gray);
    cvReleaseImage(&image_ref_gray);
    cvReleaseImage(&image_trans);
    cvReleaseImage(&image_ref);

    return 0;
}
```

right now I simply just do the image load and processing and then show it without dealing with Turtlebot. Can somebody tell me what to do plz!! Thank you guys sooooo much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229080/problem-of-using-turtlebot-to-process-image./) by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-03-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on 2016-03-15**:
I haven't worked with opencv but I used ROS-PCL.
There I get the point cloud using ROS messages then convert it to PCL data and process the data then covert it back to ROS message.
I think for opencv also should work the same.
btw you define a ros node and you never used it, is it correct way?

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-03-15**:
I don't know. I just guess it may need that. I plan to do as you said too, get image from ROS, convert it to Opencv Image, do the processing and change it back, I just don't know what else should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used several ROS_INFO, and it came with this error, I don't know what it means.

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.9-2precise-20141231-1923/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3737
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.9-2precise-20141231-1923/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

---

Originally posted by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) with karma: 62 on 2016-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-03-15**:
You should be using the opencv 2 functions, all functions starting with cv are the old functions that probably need you to preallocate space for images. Use cv::Mat instead of IplImage as well.

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-03-15**:
I have to use the old function cvCvtColor to convert RGB image to gray scale image, but Mat won't work for this, but I figure it out the problem, I have to replace my file name with the path, otherwise it cannot find the image.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-03-16**:
cv::Mat is totally fine to convert rgb images to gray scale, just use the function cvtColor and not cvCvtColor

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-03-16**:
oh OK, I didn't know that.... Thanks a lot!